# How to extract four unsigned short ints from one long long int?

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

Suppose I have one long long int and want to take its bits and construct four unsigned short ints out of it.

Particular order doesn't matter much here.

I generally know that I need to shift bits and truncate to the size of unsigned short int.  But I think I may make some weird mistake somewhere, so I ask.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union ui64 {
    uint64_t one;
    uint16_t four[4];
};

int
main()
{
    union ui64 number = {0x123456789abcdef0};
    printf("%x %x %x %x\n", number.four[0], number.four[1],
                            number.four[2], number.four[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would this be influenced by little/big-endian?

Comment: Yes, you get different results for big-endian systems vs little-endian ones.

Comment: It's definitely a quick-and-hacky solution, on the same order as: "@numbers = unpack 'S4', pack 'Q', $number;" in Perl

Comment: Will fail nastily on e.g. a Cray and a TI DSP, to name but a few CPUs where short is/can be 32 bits.

Comment: I 100% agree that this solution is not portable at all. Perhaps I should amend the answer to use inttypes.h. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
(unsigned short)((((unsigned long long int)value)>>(x))&(0xFFFF))
```

where `value` is your `long long int`, and `x` is 0, 16, 32 or 48 for the four shorts.

Comment: The catch with bitshifting is that in C/C++ the behavior is undefined for negative numbers.

Comment: For negative "value" it's not undefined, it's implementation-defined. For negative "x" it's undefined, but that never happens here. And the storage format of a negative integer is implementation-defined too (within certain possibilities), so on that score this is no worse than using a union.

Comment: I don't care if the shift sign-extends the value, I'm masking out all but the bottom sixteen bits. Those are well-defined.

Comment: I think Alexander is pointing out that the result of a right shift on a negative signed quantity need not be either 0-fill or sign-fill. It can be anything, as long as the compiler documents what. At least in C++. I haven't checked the C standard too. On "almost all" compilers you're right, though.

Comment: You got me: the right wording from the standard is "implementation-defined". I think the easiest fix for the solution in this answer is to convert value into an unsigned types first. Then the solution is superior to structs, because it yields the same results on big- and little-endian architectures.

Comment: "implementation-defined" means a C++ compiler could in principle generate code that, say, does nothing, if the the left-hand side of the right-shift operator is negative.

Comment: This would take care at least of the little/big-endian problem in the union-based answers

Comment: I understand that in reality on most compilers the right-shift either fills the left bits with 0 or propagates the sign, but it's better to be on the safe side by converting "value" to unsigned first.

Comment: Yes, I'd do that too - signed -> unsigned conversion is defined (in C++ at least, I still haven't checked C). So the result is the same everywhere, provided only that the types have the MIN/MAX values you expect.

Comment: Edited, then, for what it's worth. Though I've never come across an implementation that did anything other than sign-extend I guess it's better to be safe.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I wonder if there's any particular reason why the Standard's rules for right-shifting negative numbers, or coercion of large values to undersized signed types, don't specify any behavioral requirements?  From what I can tell, it would be perfectly legitimate for an implementation to specify that for all negative x, `x>>y` will yield 42, or will yield y, or compute the number in any side-effect-free fashion the implementation author likes, making `x>>y` with negative `x` essentially useless in strictly-conforming code, even if such code would be equally happy with...

Comment: ...any means of evaluation that any "remotely-normal" implementation might plausibly use.

Comment: @supercat: I expect it's because they didn't want to prevent implementations just using the architecture's shift opcode, and for some reason weren't confident they could provide a list of options that would include all "remotely normal" current and future architectures. The current situation is that those strictly conforming programs need to check whether an integer is negative before shifting, *unless the programmer knows it's non-negative*. On any architecture where the shift opcode didn't produce conforming behaviour, the compiler would have to emit code to check all shifts.

Comment: @SteveJessop: It makes sense to have the behavior be implementation-defined for ones'-complement or sign-magnitude architectures, since there are advantages to having an implementation act upon a number's representation, but there are also advantages to computing the same value as a two's-complement architecture when possible (a uint-to-int-to-uint cast under such rules would round-trip all values other than UINT_MAX/2, and signed shift-right would offer floored division semantics which differ from those of signed division in ways which are often useful).  There might also be some cases...

Comment: ...where alternative computations might be helpful in an implementation that uses two's-complement math but has different padding on signed and unsigned numbers.  For an implementation that uses two's-complement integers with no padding, however, the only plausible variation I could imagine in hardware would be a lack of a signed-extending right shift (and I have seen hardware like that), and even if a sign-extending right shift needed more code than a non-sign-extending one, I would regard `x = (int)((unsigned)x>>1)` to be no less clear than `x>>1` in the case where...

Comment: ...zero-padding semantics were appropriate. I agree that *as the Standard is presently written*, code that wishes to perform a sign-extended right shift must jump through some hoops to accomplish that. My question is whether any useful purpose is served by having the Standard written that way. To my mind, if 90%+ of compilers would allow an operation to be written in a fashion which is clearer (and on some compilers would likely run more efficiently as well) than any strictly-conforming way of writing it, the Standard should acknowledge that as normative, define a macro indicating...

Comment: ...whether a compiler adheres to that convention, and define compliance-related terms for programs that will work on all compilers that adhere to specified normative conventions even if they won't work on all compilers.  E.g. "Program X is strictly-compliant when used with compilers meeting normative standards for type-2 integer semantics, type-3 pointer semantics, and an `int` size of 32 bits or larger."  Alas, things are going in the opposite direction; compilers writers have little interest in supporting constructs that would have worked on 99% of compilers written from 1989 to 2009.

Answer (score 2):

```
union LongLongIntToThreeUnsignedShorts {
   long long int long_long_int;
   unsigned short int short_ints[sizeof(long long int) / sizeof(short int)];
};
```

That should do what you are thinking about, without having to mess around with bit shifting.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the struct won't have padding between short ints?

Comment: Ooops - I originally wrote about three unsigned ints. That probably mislead you. Sorry for that. Your answer was helpful anyway.

Comment: It was <code>unsigned short int</code> originally (probably 2 bytes each -- that's OK). My point was that unless you're certain about the padding/alignment rules, that struct was dangerous.